# Using :after to clear floating elements

Tags: html, css

I have a list and the li's have a `float:left;`. The contents after the `<ul>` should be aligned correctly. Therefore i can build the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/8unU8/

I thought, that I can remove the `<div class="clear">` by using pseudo selectors like :after.

But the example is not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/

Do I always have to create a separate div to clear floating elements?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/1/

Comment: This is how to do it. but please note the point in my answer about semantics.

Comment: Just a minor info: `::after` with double colon is the recommended way of targeting pseudo-elements.

Comment: Every browser that supports the double colon (::) CSS3 syntax also supports just the (:) syntax, but IE 8 only supports the single-colon, so for now, it's recommended to just use the single-colon for best browser support.

:: is the newer format indented to distinguish pseudo content from pseudo selectors. If you don't need IE 8 support, feel free to use the double-colon.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: why should we to put this: "content: '';
    display: block;" ? and what if you want a inline wrapper ?

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't it's enough to do something like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two></li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ul li {float: left;}


.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
   display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
   height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work as well:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 */
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Give the class `clearfix` to the *parent* element, for example your `ul` element.

Sources [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) and [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: display: table can add extra spacing; I use display: block instead

Answer (score 0):

The text 'dasda' will never not be within a tag, right? Semantically and to be valid HTML it as to be, just add the clear class to that:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/2/

Comment: It's not semantics at all. 1) We always clear parent element if his child have float on it for example as per your answer if i want to give background into the UL it's not cover the LI's because UL is not clear & 2) I have a question Why you give clear Class in a separate DIV before P. if you give to P only it's also work

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.wrapper:after {
    content : '\n';
}
```

Much like solution provided by Roko. It allows to insert/change content using : after and :before psuedo. For details check
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html