# How to Clear float for ul

Tags: css

I have a similar problem found here - [Using :after to clear floating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699343/using-after-to-clear-floating-elements)

and its demo solution:
    http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/1/

However it still does not solve my situation:

What I m trying to do is to pass background of ul to li, by using float ul as well.

As a result I have no way to clear float except to add a div outside ul to clear the float. Is there a better way?

**HTML**

```
Text Before

<ul class="wrapper">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>       
  <li>test3</li>
  <li style="background:#555">test4</li>
</ul>

Text After
```

Here is an updated problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/456/

What I m trying to get is that:

"Text Before" should be before the ul

and "Text After" should be after the ul

Thanks all for the solution, the best goes for connexo:

ul: display:table-cell for above/below
ul: display:inline-block for before/after

no need to float, so that there is no need to clear float, the less the better

Comment: When you say before and after, do you mean the text should be above/below the `ul`, or to the left/right of the `ul`?

Comment: I m pretty happy with ul as inline-block solved "Before" and "After". However your question inspired me to ask, what if "Above" and "Below"?

Comment: See my proposed solution for both left/right and above/below- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32042822/438581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `float: left;`, use `display: inline-block;` on your `ul.wrapper`.

https://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/460/

For new lines between elements, use `display: table-cell;` for your `ul.wrapper`. Instead of making your `li { float: left; }`, use `display: inline-block;`. To avoid unwanted whitespace issues, set the parent's `font-size: 0;` and reset to the font-size you need on the `li`.

https://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/464/

Comment: According to my question, your solution is the best. "Before" and "After" - Now I m wondering is you can make it "Above" and "Below" as well?

Comment: Easy. Check second solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clever clear fix: table-cell for above/below, inline-block for before/after

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div{
    background: #888;
}
.wrapper {
    list-style-type: none;  
    background: #888;
    display:inline-block;  
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
     
   
}

.wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
Text Before

<ul class="wrapper">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>       
    <li>test3</li>
    <li style="background:#555">test4</li>
</ul>

Text After
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want the UL background span across the whole line, that's why I use float for UL to kill the unwanted background

Answer (score 0):

See Brett DeWoody's comment. In case you wish you place `<ul>` element inline between these texts, you could place them in its container. For example, let it sit in the span like this:

```
<p>Text Before</p>

<ul class="wrapper">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>       
  <li>test3</li>
  <li style="background:#555">test4</li>
</ul>

<p>Text After</p>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #888;
}
.wrapper li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EyNnk/462/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left;` from ul , Li
and add `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the before and after text to be to the left/right of the `<ul>` add `display:inline-block` to `.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #888;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/eub5wvb9/).

If you want the before and after text to be on the top/bottom of the `<ul> add`display:block`to the`.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #888;
  display:block;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/vz8ursx8/).

Comment: For the second demo (Above and Below) . Is it possible to clear the unwanted background of UL and make it looks like that of Demo one

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or mockup of how you want it to look?

Comment: I've updated [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/vz8ursx8/) so the `<ul>` appears as it does in demo 1 @SIDU. http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/vz8ursx8/