# Use Pseudo-elements to add clear both after specific class

Tags: html, css

I want to add `clear: both` to specific element by using `::after`, I expect it to be like this.

```css
.name {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
}
.value {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

But when I delete empty `div` and add pseudo element `:after` to `.value` it doesn't work as I expect.

```css
.name {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
}
.value {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.value:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
</div>
```

So why it doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using :after to clear floating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699343/using-after-to-clear-floating-elements)

Comment: @CoolGuy I've seen that question before, I edited .value:after but I doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because OP has tried something similar and is asking why it is not working for them.

Comment: You need to set the `clear:both` to the parent div `:before'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the element that is being used to clear the floats. Though `.value:after` makes it sound as though the pseudo-element is added *after* the element with `class='value'`, it is not exactly added after that element in reality. The pseudo-element is in-fact a child of the `.value` element and is added *after the content* of that element. So, the float that is getting cleared by it is *within the element*.

When we use the Dev Tools or the Inspector, the below is the actual structure that would be seen.

```html
<div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value
      ::after <!-- This is where the pseudo-element is actually inserted -->
  </div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
</div>
```

```css
.name {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
}
.value {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.value:after {
  content: 'Some content';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
</div>
```

---

The solution for this case is simply to add the `clear: both` within each `.name` element selector. This would float the element and also clear the prior floats.

```css
.name {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.value {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="value">Value</div>
</div>
```