# How to use float and still have the child div inside the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I want to put three images at the center of a page. In the following code, when I use float, the image jumps out of the parent div with class "centered". Is there any way that I can keep the child div inside the parent div?

HTML:

```
<div class="centered">
  <div id="M">
    <img src="images/M.png">
    <img src="images/M.png">
    <img src="images/M.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    width: 1500px;
}

.centered img {
    display: block;
}

#M {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using :after to clear floating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699343/using-after-to-clear-floating-elements)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4muaq1f7/

Comment: I want to put 3 pictures side by side

Comment: I've updated your question because in your original question you said _I want to put **an image** at the center of the page_ and then your code below included a single image. Centering a row of 3 pictures side by side is quite a different question from centering a single image.

Comment: @Rounin - yes, thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add sudo element just after your .centered div to clear the float after it.

```
.centered:after{
   content: "";
   display:table;
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the image, give it a width and a left and right margin of `auto`:

```css
img {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 12px auto;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<img />
```

If you want to center the image inside a `1500px` wide `div.centered` with a `3px` green border, do the same:

```css
img {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 12px auto;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
<img />
</div>
```